# How to format a 2d array to fit a Soduku board from an input file. Python

Tags: python, arrays, sudoku

So I'm currently having some troubles formatting a 9x9 board that I obtained from a data file. What I am supposed to do is to read the data from the input files, arrange the data in a way that is similar to a sudoku puzzle. Later I need to create a function that reads every 3x3 block and gives True if it's a valid block (meaning that numbers from 1-9 won't repeat itself.

My code works for a single block of 3x3 data from an input file but it does not work for a larger file 9x9.

This is the file

```
9
1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3
4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 4
7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9
1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3
4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 5
7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9
1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3
4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 4
7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9
```

My function that reads the data and stores in an array

```
import numpy as np


def read_file(file_name):
    """
    :param file_name: Is the name of a text file, you do not need to enter the extention ".txt"
    :return: returns an array that encapsulates all the data from the input files
    """
    f = open(file_name, "r")
    data = f.read().split()
    organized_data = np.array(data)
    organized_data = organized_data.astype(np.int)
    return organized_data
```

and the code snippet that supposed to convert then into an array similar to a sudoku puzze

```
a = read_file("simplified_sudoku_provideddata/sudoku5.txt")
print(a)


newarr = a[1:].reshape(a[0], a[0])
print(newarr)
```

This gives me

```
[[1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]
 [4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 4]
 [7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9]
 [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]
 [4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 5]
 [7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9]
 [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 2 3]
 [4 5 6 5 6 4 6 5 4]
 [7 8 9 9 8 7 8 7 9]]
```

I'm having troubles coming up with a solution where I get

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],
 [3 2 1 5 6 4 9 8 7],
 [1 2 3 6 5 4 9 7 9],
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],
 [3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7],
 [1 2 3 6 5 5 8 7 9],
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],.. and so on
```

is the mistake in my first function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using numpy, but you could try this and convert it to an array afterwards:

```py
# import numpy as np (no longer needed for my code)

def read_file(file_name):
    """
    :param file_name: Is the name of a text file, you need to enter the extension ".txt"
    :return: returns an array that encapsulates all the data from the input files
    """

    return [int(n.strip()) for n in open(file_name, "r").read().split()] # smaller and more compact

def split(lst, n): # this entire function is adapted code from another stackoverflow user
    """
    :param lst: is the list to be split evenly into n chunks
    :param n: is the int of chunks lst is to be split into
    :return: returns a list of n lists containing chunks of lst
    """

    quotient, remainder = divmod(len(iterable), n)
    output = []
    stop = 0
    for i in range(n):
        start = stop
        stop += quotient + 1 if i + 1 <= remainder else quotient
        output.append(list(iter(iterable[start:stop])))
    return output

a = read_file("simplified_sudoku_provideddata/sudoku5.txt")
print(a) # note that this will include the '9' at the start (which I assume indicates the size of the square)
print()
newarr = split(a[1:], a[0])
print(newarr)
```

which should give you:

```py
[9,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,4,7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,5,7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,4,7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9]

[[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3],[4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,4],[7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9],[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3],[4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,5],[7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9],[1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3],[4,5,6,5,6,4,6,5,4],[7,8,9,9,8,7,8,7,9]]
```